# couldn't view image url even after setting to public aws s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

https://thestobookimages.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mark.jpeg this image is in my aws s3 bucket and the bucket permissions are set to allow all public. But still it shows access denied.

Permissions,
[image]

While trying to access,
[image]

Tried with both ACL enabled and disable, but still access denied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have to edit bucket policy to allow public read.

```
   {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": "*",
          "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject"
          ],
          "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/*"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: How to access from a specific domain alone?

Comment: You can use the policy shown here: 
https://www.eternalsoftsolutions.com/blog/how-to-restrict-s3-bucket-for-specific-domain-name/